# How to implement Primefaces Autocomplete's completeMethod for items of Enum Class?

Tags: jsf, autocomplete, primefaces

I want to have an Autocomplete which should show suggestions of items which I specify in an Enum class:

```
public enum Units {

      PERCENT, MILLIMETER, METER, NUMBER
}
```

I have a method in some class which returns these values:

```
public final List<Unit> getUnits() {
    List<Unit> items = new ArrayList<Unit>();
    Unit[] units = Unit.values();
    for (int i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
        items.add(units[i]);
    }
    return items;
}
```

How should I implement the completeMethod for autocomplete since there are no setters and getters for the items which is to be suggested? I am new to Primefaces and JSF, so appreciate some help here.

Comment: Did the solution posted below work for you?

Comment: @akoskm - Yes, it did. Thanks! Marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have access to enum names with `units[i]` or through `units[s].name()`. You can also convert a String value to enum with `Unit.valueOf("PERCENT")`. Your `completeMethod` will look like:

```
public List<String> completeEnum(String query) {
    List<String> match = new ArrayList<String>();
    Unit[] units = Unit.values();
    for (int i = 0; i < units.length; i++) {
        if (units[i].name().contains(query))
            match.add(units[i]);
    }
    return match;
}
```

Give a plain String property for `autocomplete` value:

```
<p:autocomplete value="#{bean.enumString}" completeMethod="#{bean.completeEnum}"/>
```

and convert the selected string to `Unit` in getters/setters:

```
private Unit unit;
private String enumString;

public String getEnumString() {
    return this.enumString;
}

public void setEnumString(String enumString) {
    this.unit = Unit.valueOf(enumString);
}
```

Note that `Unit.valueOf(String)` can throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` if the provided String cannot be converted to `Unit`.